# MySQL query works in database but not in php script - returns one row in script

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to build a complex SQL SELECT statement to manipulate MySQL data in a report. However, when I try to use the following query in my php script, it brings up one row result. When I copy and paste the same query in phpmyadmin, the query works perfectly. I'm not sure what the problem is. When testing the embedded query without it being an alias table, the query works perfectly in the application. Any Ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

MY query and result set (NOTE:: I am using dhtmlxgrid to view the data - this works just fine):

```
$sql = "SELECT x.productid 
FROM (SELECT invoices.id, invoices.orderdate, lineitems.invoiceid, lineitems.productid, lineitems.quantity, SUM(lineitems.quantity) as totalqty, products.id AS prodid, products.description, products.partnumber 
FROM invoices 
INNER JOIN lineitems 
ON (invoices.id = lineitems.invoiceid) 
INNER JOIN products 
ON (lineitems.productid = products.id) 
WHERE (invoices.orderdate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-02-07') 
GROUP BY invoices.id) x 
GROUP BY x.productid";


    //echo $sql;
    $res = mysql_query ($sql);
    if($res){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            //create xml tag for grid row
            print("<row id=' ".$row['id']." '>");
            //print("<cell><![CDATA["."<a href='products_printlayup.php?id=".$row['id']."'target="."'_blank' >".$row['Part Number']."</a>"."]]></cell>");
            print("<cell><![CDATA["."<b>".$row['productid']."<b>"."]]></cell>");
            print("<cell><![CDATA["."<b>".$row['productid']."<b>"."]]></cell>");
            print("<cell><![CDATA[".$row['productid']."]]></cell>");
            print("<cell><![CDATA[".$row['productid']."]]></cell>");

            //close xml tag for the row
            print("</row>");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you close your `while` and `if`? What does your errorhandling say? Have you tried to `var_dump` your result? What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: The mysql_* functions have been deprecated and should not be used (http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).  Also your code is incomplete.  We will need the rest to help debug.

Comment: Ahhh I just got it lol I needed to include 'x.id' as that was my unique column from the subquery. Without that, I couldn't properly group my outter query. But thank you!

Comment: *and yes I am aware of the mysql_* library issue. I am updating the code as a build the page.